# D3 data processing choice

Tags: javascript, database, d3.js

I have a question about which kind of data I should send to client for visualization:

I have an web that needs to display both processed data and database-like data(Processed one is from database-like)
So now I have 2 choices:

1. Send to client Database-like data and process the logic there to get the processed data
2. Send both processed data and database-like data. Redundant but ease of use

I would like to hear about your opinions n regard of these 2 approaches. And they are also in context of using d3

Comment: it depends on the data amount, the processing complexity and data format, but I think the processing logic should not be duplicated => 2.

Comment: also depends on the performance hit by running the logic to get the processed data.